# Can't test because of Error: Undefined name 'platformViewRegistry'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am rendering an iframe with flutter. But when trying to run tests I get the following error

```
Error: Undefined name 'platformViewRegistry'.
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(viewType, viewFactory);
```

This is because the test is mocking dependencies which include a router which includes an import the iframe. This is the class that is the cause of the error

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'view_registry.dart';

class BrowserViewRegistry implements ViewRegistry {
  @override
  void registerViewFactory(String viewType, dynamic Function(int viewId) viewFactory) {
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(viewType, viewFactory);
  }
}

ViewRegistry makeViewRegistry() {
  return BrowserViewRegistry();
}
```

So I tried to solve it with a conditional import

```
import 'package:iframe_widget/src/view_registry/view_registry.dart';
export 'view_registry.dart';
import 'view_registry_browser.dart' if (dart.library.test) 'view_registry_test.dart';

ViewRegistry makeTestableViewRegistry() {
  return makeViewRegistry();
}
```

Where the test registry does nothing.

import 'view_registry.dart';

```
class TestViewRegistry implements ViewRegistry {
  @override
  void registerViewFactory(String viewType, dynamic Function(int viewId) viewFactory) {
    // do nothing
  }
}

ViewRegistry makeViewRegistry() {
  return TestViewRegistry();
}
```

But this does not work. How could I solve this issue without having to change my dependencies? Ideally a solution that can do a conditional import when it's in a testing environment. And if that is not possible what are other possible solutions to this problem?